# Canada Post 'lookup postal code' screen scrape code

Tags: php, codeigniter

I don't want to reinvent the wheel.

Is anyone aware of php/curl code to populate address data in Canada Post's 'Find a Postal Code' page http://www.canadapost.ca/cpotools/apps/fpc/personal/findByAdvanced?execution=e1s1
and return the valid postal code.

I thought it would make a great address verification routine.

Comment: I've always felt validating physical addresses should be like validating email addresses.  Mail them a fortune cookie and force them to type their fortune into a web page to verify they received it.

Comment: CanadaPost has a set of web services and online tools that should be used instead of screen scraping.

http://www.canadapost.ca/cpo/mc/business/campaigns/northbound/borderfree.jsf

Answer (score 3):

Check out http://www.geocoder.ca too. They have a postal code lookup web service. They also have free postalcode/city data here:

http://geocoder.ca/?freedata=1

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just use the API for the webservice they provide?

Then you don't have to scrape a screen...